# Video not playing in carousel

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add video to the carousel of a webpage but the video is showing and not playing, all the buttons like play/sound/pause/buffering are showing but the video is not playing. The video is only playing if I am making it fullscreen and clicking on the play button. After playing if I am escaping the full-screen mode still it is playing. So how can I include autoplay to avoid playing the video only when I am clicking full screen?

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
            <video width="1400" autoplay="autoplay" height="400" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     </video>

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1200x400?text=Another Image Maybe" alt="Image">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
    </div>      
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this a video without sound? Otherwise this might now have anything to do with the slider in the first place, but could simply be the browser blocking you from autoplaying a video when the user has not explicitly asked for that to happen.

Comment: The video has sound and I have change it from VLC to Windows Media Player

Answer (score 2):

You have a missing "!

```
<video width="1400" autoplay="autoplay" height="400" controls>
```

would be right

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [playsinline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-playsinline), it worked for me.

```
<video playsinline="playsinline" width="1400" autoplay="autoplay" height="400" muted="muted" loop="loop">
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Thank you. The video is now autoplaying but audio is absent.

Comment: you can just take off muted="muted" and the audio will play normally

Comment: When I am removing the muted portion, instead of video only a still image is appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `autoplay` instead of `autoplay="autoplay"`

Also you have syntax error before `height` you are missing double-quote.

```
<video width="1400" autoplay="autoplay height="400" controls>
```

Here is working example

```
<video width="400" controls autoplay>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
```